# How can I configure the Visual Stuidio 2010 "Test Results" window to automatically expand the "Group by" sections after a test run?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tdd, mstest

I am currently engaged in a large C#.NET 4.0 project and am doing so with a TDD aproach.

In our unit tests we have adopted a naming pattern based on the one in Roy Overshore's "[The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Art-Unit-Testing-Examples/dp/1933988274)" book. Essentially for each class "XXX" we have a coresponding "XXXFacts" test class and each [TestMethod] method in that class is named with a pattern of "[Method/Prop name]*[sate/result]*[preconditions]" for example "AccessLevel_IsInvalid_WhenNotAuthenticated"

Now intially to see the test results I just configured the test results window to add the ClassName column which looks OK, but takes up much horizonal screen real estate as you can see;
[image]

I then discovered the "Group By" option in the window. This does as the name suggests and grouped the output by class name, so I can remove the repeating coulmn and gain more room for any eror message text.

however every time I run my tests the view I am given has the group by contents collapsed like this;

[image]

What I would like to do is somehow configure the Visual Stuidio 2010 Test Results Window to automatically expand the "Group by" sections after a test run so it looks like this immediatley after a test run;

[image]

At the very least if it could expand a group that contais a FAILED test that would be a massive plus.

I know this is just plain lazy but opening all those groups after every run on a TDD project is already getting old!

I have looked but failed to find a configuration option for this in the tools dialog, but perhaps I i've been looking in the wrong place. I do hope so.

Comment: +1 I would like to know how the test result display options in general can be saved.

Comment: It's not a real answer to your question, but you might want to try Resharper's Unit Test Runner. When you have large projects, it's provides more options to find your way through all those unit tests.